# database Array to string converted divided | sign

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to filter some words from database with string match() but event gives array form.
I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql module in order to query the database for column name

```
    con.query('SELECT name FROM droid_hastag_banned', function(error,result){

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            var arr = result[i].name;

        }

    });
```

Currently the query output is that if I'm using for each, else result[0].name; results only one line

```
RT
@Alex_TNT
@TopU3DAssets
@LatestAssetBot
@IndieLeverage
@Parodossy
@GameArtSleuth
```

I need to have this format

```
.match(/^RT|RT|@TopU3DAssets|@LatestAssetBot|@IndieLeverage|@Parodossy|@GameArtSleuth|@Alex_TNT/)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply concatenate the results:

```
result = [{"name":"@Alex_TNT"},{"name":"@TopU3DAssets"},{"name":"@LatestAssetBot"}, {"name":"@IndieLeverage"},{"name":"@Parodossy"},{"name":"@GameArtSleuth"}]

result=result.map(function(x){ return x.name; });
exp = "/^RT|RT|"+result.join("|")+"/";
r = RegExp(exp);
console.log(r.test("@Alex_TNT"));
```

A possible implementation is used in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvygcwa9/1/).
An explanation of `Array.prototype.join` is found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). `Array.prototype.map()` is explained [ibd.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

---

*Explanation*:

You got the result in form of an `array` containing `objects`.
Besides other properties, the resulting objects had a property `name`.
To extract only the name from the object, I used the `Array.prototype.map()` method, which does nothing more than applying a function to each member of an array: in this case `return x.name`. The object-array was `mapped` to a string array.

`exp` is simply string concatenation combined with usage of `Array.prototype.join()` to get a string of the form `"xx|xx|xx"`.

No magic involved ;)

Comment: This is the result - /^RT|RT|[object Object]|[object Object]|[object Object]|[object Object]|[object Object]|[object Object]|[object Object]|[object Object]/   - That's why I used for index

Comment: My bad ;) You have to concat the `.name` of course ;)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined. I tried join() method before and it did the same error

Comment: This should look better.

Comment: Thank you very much seems to work, and I could not resolve the problem alone it seems to complex looking at the solution.

Comment: I added an explanation :]